# AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, pytest

I have a problem with pytest, I just followed the documentation here https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/ so when I run this command **pytest** in my terminal an I got this:

```
 packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 168, in exec_module
        exec(co, module.__dict__)
      File "/home/youssfi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faker/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from faker.factory import Factory
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "/home/youssfi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 168, in exec_module
        exec(co, module.__dict__)
      File "/home/youssfi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faker/factory.py", line 7, in <module>
        from faker.config import AVAILABLE_LOCALES, DEFAULT_LOCALE, PROVIDERS
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "/home/youssfi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 168, in exec_module
        exec(co, module.__dict__)
      File "/home/youssfi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faker/config.py", line 11, in <module>
        PROVIDERS = find_available_providers(
      File "/home/youssfi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faker/utils/loading.py", line 57, in find_available_providers
        for mod in list_module(providers_mod) if mod != '__pycache__'
      File "/home/youssfi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faker/utils/loading.py", line 35, in list_module
        return [name for _, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.iter_modules([path]) if is_pkg]
      File "/home/youssfi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faker/utils/loading.py", line 35, in <listcomp>
        return [name for _, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.iter_modules([path]) if is_pkg]
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pkgutil.py", line 129, in iter_modules
        for i in importers:
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pkgutil.py", line 419, in get_importer
        importer = path_hook(path_item)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1594, in path_hook_for_FileFinder
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1469, in __init__
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 177, in _path_isabs
    AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

My version is Python 3.8.10.

This is my code:

```
# content of test_sample.py
def inc(x):
    return x + 1


def test_answer():
    assert inc(3) == 5
```

this is my file Python:

> test_sample.py

### can someone have any idea about this?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the `faker` library - you may confirm this by uninstalling it, or try to upgrade it if you need it.

Comment: Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/issues/1439) in faker which has been fixed meanwhile, so an upgrade of `faker` should fix your problem.

Comment: The error message indicates that something received a `pathlib.Path` but expected to receive a string. Often, this is a library bug, and it should be updated to also accept `Path` objects.

Comment: still the same problem after installing faker

Comment: Hm, what version have you installed? And have you tried to uninstall it?

Comment: it's working when i changed faker 8.3.0 to faker 13.4.4.